# this code represents an implementation of a multithreadServer?

Tags: java, multithreading

My teacher showed us code to implement an application server multithread but I am a little bit confused. is this an implementation of a multithread server? I didn't understand if it's so. 
We suppose to create an object `Server s = new Server(port_number)`. Could we assert it is a multithread server ?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class Server implements Runnable
{
private ServerSocket serverSocket;

public MainCenterServer(int port){

    try
    {

        this.serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
    }
    catch(IOException ioe) {ioe.printStackTrace(); }

    new Thread(this, "Server").start();
}

@Override
public void run()
{

    while(true)
    {
        try
        {
            Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();

        }
        catch(IOException ioe) {ioe.printStackTrace(); }

    }
}   
}
```

Comment: If by "multithread server" you mean a server which creates new threads for each client, then no, it is not. If by "multithread server" you mean a server which accepts multiple clients, then yes, it is, however it does nothing with the client once it accepts it.
How would you go about "asserting" that a server is multithread?

Comment: First define **multithreaded sever**

Comment: Right excuse I don't specify what I mean for multithreaded server. I mean a server that can accepts request from two or more clients.

Comment: @Jeffrey Well it's only an example. I have to continue it adding what I have in mind to do.

Comment: @Jeffrey What I don't understand is why it is a multithread server ? every request of a client it creates a different threads?

Comment: @Mazzy By your definition it is a multithreaded server because it accepts more than one client, however since it doesn't create a thread for each client it accepts it can not perform any I/O with them.

Comment: If this is the example the teacher gave, it is really bad. A thread is started up, but it is of no value, as the main thread just ends, so why not just have the main thread hold the main accept loop. Plus as others have said, theres no processing of sockets, and these are done serially, which isn't multithreaded by most peoples view of a multithreaded server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By your definition of a multithreaded server, yes, this server is multithreaded.

`new Thread(this, "Server").start()` creates a separate thread for the `run()` method to execute on. Since the `run` method has an infinite loop, it will always be waiting for a client to accept (`Socket socket = serverSocket.accept()`).